# uri_for fails to build name for Route

Tags: google-app-engine, webapp2

I am trying to build a uri using uri_for and a named Route.

This is my barebones code:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
(r'/screenshot_worker', 'mkt.ScreenshotWorker'),
webapp2.Route(r'/screenshot/<screenshot_key>', 
   handler='mkt.ScreenshotHandler', name='screenshot')
])
```

and the handler

```
class ScreenshotWorker(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):
        d = date.today().strftime('%d%m%Y')
        key = ndb.Key('Screenshot', d)
        url = self.uri_for('screenshot', screenshot_key=key) #fails
```

which fails with

```
KeyError: "Route named 'screenshot' is not defined."
```

Answer (score 0):

The handler you have defined and built URI is `ScreenshotWorker` , whereas for the Route named screenshot, the handler mentioned is `ScreenshotHandler`

Comment: I don't think it's relevant, but I do define ScreenshotHandler. If a named Route is defined, it shouldn't fail to build the URI, even if the handler is not defined (maybe you get a 404 if you try to request the generated URI)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an issue with your route definitions.  I'm not sure if it's a typo from your code excerpting or not, but the line:

`(r'/screenshot_worker', 'mkt.ScreenshotWorker'),`

is missing the leading webapp2.Route (which your second definition correctly uses), which may be breaking your entire url map.